# how to plot multilinear regression graph in python

Tags: python, plot, regression

How do I plot multilinear regression graph in python?

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import linear_model

df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/SAAD FAKHAR/OneDrive/Desktop/reg.csv")
df
```

This is the screen shot of csv file:
[image]

```py
reg=linear_model.LinearRegression()
reg.fit(df[['area','bedroom','age']],df.price)
```

Comment: :In the bottom row, the comma by "df" does not seem to fit. I know this is old, but to help newbies ( sort of like myself)